# display rows as columns for apparel products

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

i m working on e commerce website . trying to keep apparel sizes as columns
[image: here is my stock table]

**snippet without "group by productid" clause**

```
select d.id,
(case when s.sizeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as "S"  ,
(case when s.sizeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as "M",
(case when s.sizeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as "L"  ,
(case when s.sizeid = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as "XL",
(case when s.sizeid = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as "XXL"  
from datatest d
inner join stock s on d.id = s.productid
```

[image: result]

**with "group by product id" results like this**

```
select d.id,
(case when s.sizeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as "S"  ,
(case when s.sizeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as "M",
(case when s.sizeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as "L"  ,
(case when s.sizeid = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as "XL",
(case when s.sizeid = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as "XXL"  
from datatest d
inner join stock s on d.id = s.productid
group by d.id
```

[image: result]

please help me out

Comment: What do you need help with? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want is the sum of all columns for sizes, sharing the same product id.

The [SUM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function will do that for you when using `GROUP BY`

```
select d.id,
SUM( (case when s.sizeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) ) as "S"  ,
SUM( (case when s.sizeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) ) as "M",
SUM( (case when s.sizeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) ) as "L"  ,
SUM( (case when s.sizeid = 4 then 1 else 0 end) ) as "XL",
SUM( (case when s.sizeid = 5 then 1 else 0 end) ) as "XXL"  
from datatest d
inner join stock s on d.id = s.productid
group by d.id
```